# What does $\cos(x)$ to the power of $x$ represent?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

Question is self-explanatory: I've been playing around in Desmos recently and just wanted to know if anyone had an explanation for what exactly is happening when we take $\cos^x(x)$?

Comment: It would be the length of x of an opposite side to an angle the power of the angle x

Comment: When you say "what exactly is happening?", are you simply asking for the definition of $\cos^x(x)$, or are you seeking a geometric interpretation of the expression?

Comment: As Tyma says, it just means $(\cos(x))^x$. -and you’d be hard pressed to find this expression in the wild

Comment: How do you define this function for example at $x=\pi$?

Comment: Here is a [plot over the entire complex plane](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+re%28cos%28x%2By+i%29%5E%28x%2By+i%29%29%2Bi+im%28cos%28x%2By+i%29%5E%28x%2By+i%29%29%2C+-1%3Cx%3C1%2C-1%3Cy%3C1) for $\cos^z(z)$. Adjust the parameters if needed in the link.

Comment: You ask about the behavior of a software program, Desmos, without showing us what that behavior is.  Exponentiation of negative real numbers to non-integer powers is not a well-defined operation (it gives multiple values unless one specifies the computation more strictly).  So I'd expect Desmos to do something quirky in that situation.  It isn't really on-topic without clearer details.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I am guessing the question was aimed at [the curve for real $x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%28x%29%5Ex%2C+-pi%2F2%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2), at least when $\cos(x)$ is positive